# firefox installation under 12.04 server

Tags: firefox

I am new to linux and ubuntu 12.04 lts server.

Can anyone please help, **how can I run firefox under command prompt**

Comment: do you have any Graphical Interface Manually installed. Although you can issue Firefox commands from CLI but it requires GUI to be present, unless no Use at all. There are text based browsers like [Elinks](http://elinks.or.cz/) and [Lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/lynx2.8.7/index.html).

Comment: Got that , i was hoping with the intention that OP will edit and add some relevant information in Question through that. Nothing more .

Answer (score 5):

If you installed Ubuntu Server 12.04 you'll have to install the runtime environment as well. And if you are doing this remotely, you need to use `ssh -X` in your remote connection command (do NOT automatically assume that will work)

Doing `sudo apt-get install firefox` will install ffox and its dependencies, as well as a runtime environment (I believe).  Note that when you say 'how can i run ffox under command prompt', you need to be more specific, i.e. are you trying to run it from a terminal so it opens on the system its installed in, or are you trying to run it in the terminal itself, such that you have a terminal web browser.  Ffox does not work in the command line as a web browser if you are not using a GUI envirionment.  (take a look at `w3m` if you need a terminal text-like browser)

Comment: You may want to appear less condescending, bolding and capsing the not...is not good practice. :p

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually NEED firefox or do you just need a web browser that works in the terminal? I would try `sudo apt-get install links` or `lynx` both of those are terminal based web browsers.

If you plan on using this installation as your main computer you might want to reinstall with the ubuntu 12.04 Desktop version, might be a bit easier for someone who is "new" to linux

Answer (score 0):

You can Run Firefox through Terminal using just single word command

syn :

```
     firefox
```

To open any other page through it, just do it like

Syn :

```
    firefox <Domain Name>
```

Example :

```
    firefox http://www.google.com
```

This is to open google.com through firefox.

If you have not properly installed firefox just type command in terminal like

Syn :

```
Sudo apt-get install firefox.
```

And Enter your password.